# Ansible EC2 keyring

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

Kind of new to ansible and EC2, and I am having troubles connecting to new instances, maybe I do not get the key pair thing yet.

In order to connect from ansible to newly created instances, how do I use key-pairs to ssh those instances instead of user and password?

Everything works if I append --private-key=keypair.pem to a second playbook, but not sure how to make that work in single playbook after creating a new instance.

kind regards

Comment: Please include the playbook/task, how you are running it, and the output.

Answer (score 0):

Olease start from [this section](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_aws.html) of documentation or look at [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/apn/getting-started-with-ansible-and-dynamic-amazon-ec2-inventory-management/)
The best way to handle this is to use the [ec2 dynamic inventory script](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script)

But if you prefer to use static inventory you may use the ansible_ssh_private_key_file parameter in your Ansible inventory `hosts.ini`.

something like this

```
[server1]
1.2.3.4 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/my.pem
[aws]
ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/aws.pem ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
ec2-1-2-3-5.compute-1.amazonaws.com ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/aws.pem ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
```